# Why is font size different in vertical direction

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts, gdi

I created two rulers - one vertical and one horizontal:

[image: Screenshot]

Now in the vertical ruler, is 'size' of the text visually larger(aprox. 5-6 pixels longer).

Why?

Relevant code:

**WM_CREATE:**

```
LOGFONT Lf = {0};

Lf.lfHeight = 12;

lstrcpyW(Lf.lfFaceName, L"Arial");

if (!g_pGRI->bHorizontal)
{
    Lf.lfEscapement = 900; // <----For vertical ruler!
}

g_pGRI->hfRuler = CreateFontIndirectW(&Lf);

SelectFont(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->hfRuler);
```

**WM_PAINT:**

```
    SetTextColor(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->cBorder);

    SetBkColor(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->cBackground);

    SetTextAlign(g_pGRI->hdRuler, TA_CENTER);

#define INCREMENT 10

    WCHAR wText[16] = {0};

    if (g_pGRI->bHorizontal)
    {
        INT ixTicks = RECTWIDTH(g_pGRI->rRuler) / INCREMENT;

        for (INT ix = 0; ix < ixTicks + 1; ix++)
        {
            MoveToEx(g_pGRI->hdRuler, INCREMENT * ix, 0, NULL);

            if (ix % INCREMENT == 0)
            {
                //This is major tick.

                LineTo(g_pGRI->hdRuler, INCREMENT * ix, g_pGRI->lMajor);

                wsprintfW(wText, L"%d", INCREMENT * ix);

                TextOutW(g_pGRI->hdRuler, INCREMENT * ix + 1, g_pGRI->lMajor + 1, wText, CHARACTERCOUNT(wText));
            }
            else
            {
                //This is minor tick.

                LineTo(g_pGRI->hdRuler, INCREMENT * ix, g_pGRI->lMinor);
            }
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        INT iyTicks = RECTHEIGHT(g_pGRI->rRuler) / INCREMENT;

        for (INT iy = 0; iy < iyTicks + 1; iy++)
        {
            MoveToEx(g_pGRI->hdRuler, 0, INCREMENT * iy, NULL);

            if (iy % INCREMENT == 0)
            {
                //This is major tick.

                LineTo(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->lMajor, INCREMENT * iy);

                wsprintfW(wText, L"%d", INCREMENT * iy);

                TextOutW(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->lMajor + 1, INCREMENT * iy + 1, wText, CHARACTERCOUNT(wText));
            }
            else
            {
                //This is minor tick.

                LineTo(g_pGRI->hdRuler, g_pGRI->lMinor, INCREMENT * iy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a ClearType anti-aliasing artifact.  Use a tool like SysInternals' ZoomIt to see what's going on.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank for hint, but if I turn off ClearType via Control Panel, I still see vertical text larger.

Comment: I looked at your screenshot with Magnifier, and it seems even your tick marks are antialiased, yet I see nothing in the code that could have done that.  Is this really the code that generated the image in that PNG?  Was the image post-processed or did it pass through some lossy compression method?

Comment: Is the question really just "Why?" or do you also want to know what you can do to make them look the same?

Comment: Is the question really just "Why?" or do you also want to know what you can do to make them look the same? -----Both :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Background

There are several different schemes for rasterizing text in a legible way when the text is small relative to the size of a pixel.  For example, if the stroke width is supposed to be 1.25 pixels wide, you either have to round it off to a whole number of pixels, use antialiasing, or use subpixel rendering (like ClearType).  Rounding is usually controlled by "hints" built into the font by the font designer.

Hinting is the main reason why text width doesn't always scale exactly with the text height.  For example, if, because of rounding, the left hump of a lowercase `m` is a pixel wider than the right one, a hint might tell the renderer to round the width up to make the letter symmetric.  The result is that the character is a tad wider relative to its height than the ideal character.

### This issue

What's likely happening here is that when GDI renders the string horizontally, each subsequent character may start at a fractional position, which is simulated by antialiasing or subpixel (ClearType) rendering.  But, when rendering vertically, it appears that each subsequent character's starting position is rounded up to the next whole pixel, which tends to make the vertical text a couple pixels "longer" than its horizontal counterpart.  Effectively, the kerning is always rounded up to the next whole pixel.

It's likely that more effort was put into the common case of horizontal text rendering, making it easier to read (and possibly faster to render).  The general case of rendering at any other angle may have been implemented in a simpler manner, working glyph-by-glyph instead of with the entire string.

### Things to Try

If you want them to look that same, you'll probably have to make a small compromise in the visual quality of the horizontal labels.  Here are a few things I can think of to try:

1. Render the labels with regular antialiasing instead of ClearType subpixel rendering.  (You can do this by setting the lfQuality field in the LOGFONT.)  You would then draw the horizontal labels in the normal manner.  For the vertical labels, draw them to an offscreen buffer horizontally, rotate it, and then blit the buffer to the screen.  This gives you labels that look identical.  The reason I suggest regular antialiasing is that it's invariant to the rotation.  ClearType rendering had an inherent orientation and thus cannot be rotated without creating fringing.  I've used this approach for graph labels with good results.
2. Render the horizontal labels character by character, rounding the starting point up to the next whole pixel.  This should make the horizontal labels look like the vertical ones.  Typographically, they won't look as good, but for small labels like this, it's probably less distracting than having the horizontal and vertical labels visually mismatched.
3. Another answer suggested rendering the horizontal labels with a very small, but non-zero, escapement and orientation, forcing those to go through the same rendering pipeline as the vertical labels.  This may be the easiest solution for short labels like yours.  If you had to handle longer strings of text, I'd suggest one of the first two methods.

Answer (score 3):

When using `lfEscapement`, you will often get strange behaviour as it renders text using a fairly different pipeline.

A trick would be to have `lfEscapement` set for both.  One with 900, and one with a very low value (such as `1` or even `10`.  Once you have both rendering with escapement, you should be good.

If you're still having issues with smoothing, try doing something like this:

```
BOOL bSmooth;
//Get previous smooth value.
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, &bSmooth, 0);
//Set no smoothing.
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, NULL, 0);
//Draw text.

//Return smoothing.
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, bSmooth, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer, I know about lfHeight recommendation from MSDN, but this have nothing with vertical size, because vertical size is still larger. But +1 for efforts with the problem.

Comment: @Xearinox Did you try my suggestion of setting lfEscapement to 1 for the horizontal text?  If it was the solution, I'd appreciate the bounty as my answer was posted before Adrian's and he used my answer as reference.

Comment: Yes I m trying this, but visually is still different - vertical ruler text looks like a 'sharpen' and horizontal ruler like a 'blured'.

Comment: @Xearinox As I mentioned, try `lfEscapement` of 900 for vertical, and then try `lfEscapement` of `1` or even `10`, and see if small values work like that.  If that still isn't working as I suggested, try my smoothing edit I added to my answer.

Comment: Changing escapement dont have effect, but I ll try smoothing tonight.

Comment: Sorry for delay, but my development machine is defunct now. :-(